# AdvancedCollectionView implements the ISupportIncrementalLoading interface, but it doesn't work

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp-xaml, windows-community-toolkit

UWP Community Toolkit's (now known as Windows Community Toolkit) AdvancedCollectionView collection implements the ISupportIncrementalLoading  interface, and so I'm trying to use it with my ListView to only load portions of items at one time, but the ListView still loads all items at once. What am I missing?

Here is the XAML:

```
<ListView x:Name="MyListView"
    DataFetchSize="10"
    IncrementalLoadingTrigger="Edge"
    IncrementalLoadingThreshold="10"
    ItemSource="{x:Bind ACV, Mode=TwoWay}">
</ListView>
```

And here is the code-behind:

```
public class MainPage
{
    public AdvancedCollectionView ACV { get; set; }
    // Lets say that DocCollection contains 1000 items
    public ObservableCollection<Document> DocCollection;

    public MainPage()
    {
        ACV = new AdvancedCollectionView(DocCollection, true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The [`AdvancedCollectionView`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwpcommunitytoolkit/helpers/advancedcollectionview) is a collection view implementation that support filtering, sorting and incremental loading. But according to the usage section of the document I linked,

> incremental loading: if your source collection supports the feature then AdvancedCollectionView will do as well (it simply forwards the calls)

So that the `AdvancedCollectionView` does't have incremental feature itself, it simple forwards the calls. That means the source collection you provided for the `AdvancedCollectionView` should inherit from  [`ISupportIncrementalLoading`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Xaml.Data.ISupportIncrementalLoading) interface. Also if you check the [`AdvancedCollectionView.LoadMoreItemsAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.toolkit.uwp.ui.advancedcollectionview.loadmoreitemsasync?view=uwp-toolkit-dotnet#Microsoft_Toolkit_Uwp_UI_AdvancedCollectionView_LoadMoreItemsAsync_System_UInt32_) method, it shows *Not implemented yet* which indicates `AdvancedCollectionView` doesn't implement the `ISupportIncrementalLoading` interface.

And in your case, you just use `ObservableCollection` for the source collection that doesn't support `ISupportIncrementalLoading` by default. For creating  collection views that support incremental loading please reference this [official sample](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?linkid=226854).

```
DocCollection = new GeneratorIncrementalLoadingClass<DataTest>(1000, (count) =>
{
    return new DataTest() { Country = "Ghana" + count, City = "Wa" + count };
});
DocCollection.CollectionChanged += DocCollection_CollectionChanged;
ACV = new AdvancedCollectionView(DocCollection, true);
MyListView.ItemsSource = ACV;

public class GeneratorIncrementalLoadingClass<T> : IncrementalLoadingBase
{
    public GeneratorIncrementalLoadingClass(uint maxCount, Func<int, T> generator)
    {
        _generator = generator;
        _maxCount = maxCount;
    }

    protected async override Task<IList<object>> LoadMoreItemsOverrideAsync(System.Threading.CancellationToken c, uint count)
    {
        uint toGenerate = System.Math.Min(count, _maxCount - _count);

        // Wait for work 
        await Task.Delay(10);

        // This code simply generates
        var values = from j in Enumerable.Range((int)_count, (int)toGenerate)
                     select (object)_generator(j);
        _count += toGenerate;

        return values.ToArray();
    }

    protected override bool HasMoreItemsOverride()
    {
        return _count < _maxCount;
    }

    #region State

    Func<int, T> _generator;
    uint _count = 0;
    uint _maxCount;

    #endregion 
}

public abstract class IncrementalLoadingBase : IList, ISupportIncrementalLoading, INotifyCollectionChanged
{
    #region IList

    public int Add(object value)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void Clear()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public bool Contains(object value)
    {
        return _storage.Contains(value);
    }

    public int IndexOf(object value)
    {
        return _storage.IndexOf(value);
    }

    public void Insert(int index, object value)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public bool IsFixedSize
    {
        get { return false; }
    }

    public bool IsReadOnly
    {
        get { return true; }
    }

    public void Remove(object value)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void RemoveAt(int index)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public object this[int index]
    {
        get
        {
            return _storage[index];
        }
        set
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }

    public void CopyTo(Array array, int index)
    {
        ((IList)_storage).CopyTo(array, index);
    }

    public int Count
    {
        get { return _storage.Count; }
    }

    public bool IsSynchronized
    {
        get { return false; }
    }

    public object SyncRoot
    {
        get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    }

    public IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
    {
        return _storage.GetEnumerator();
    }

    #endregion

    #region ISupportIncrementalLoading

    public bool HasMoreItems
    {
        get { return HasMoreItemsOverride(); }
    }

    public Windows.Foundation.IAsyncOperation<LoadMoreItemsResult> LoadMoreItemsAsync(uint count)
    {
        if (_busy)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Only one operation in flight at a time");
        }

        _busy = true;

        return AsyncInfo.Run((c) => LoadMoreItemsAsync(c, count));
    }

    #endregion 

    #region INotifyCollectionChanged

    public event NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler CollectionChanged;

    #endregion 

    #region Private methods

    async Task<LoadMoreItemsResult> LoadMoreItemsAsync(CancellationToken c, uint count)
    {
        try
        {
            var items = await LoadMoreItemsOverrideAsync(c, count);
            var baseIndex = _storage.Count;

            _storage.AddRange(items);

            // Now notify of the new items
            NotifyOfInsertedItems(baseIndex, items.Count);

            return new LoadMoreItemsResult { Count = (uint)items.Count };
        }
        finally
        {
            _busy = false;
        }
    }

    void NotifyOfInsertedItems(int baseIndex, int count)
    {
        if (CollectionChanged == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            var args = new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add, _storage[i + baseIndex], i + baseIndex);
            CollectionChanged(this, args);
        }
    }

    #endregion

    #region Overridable methods

    protected abstract Task<IList<object>> LoadMoreItemsOverrideAsync(CancellationToken c, uint count);
    protected abstract bool HasMoreItemsOverride();

    #endregion 

    #region State

    List<object> _storage = new List<object>();
    bool _busy = false;

    #endregion 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. There was nothing in the linked official sample that gave an example on implementing ISupportIncrementalLoading. Am I missing something?

Comment: Check the scenario 8 , `IncrementalLoading`. I will  also upload the whole code in my reply you could just completed reference. @LeBrownJones

Comment: Can it be used directly in XAML as a ViewSource?